# [NSPlaceholderString initWithValidatedFormat:validFormatSpecifiers:locale:arguments:error

Tags: objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

After Update project xCode 11 to 12 App crashing while tapping Uiview with uitapgesture it's works fine with xcode 11 but not in xcode 12 , kindl anyone lookin to it
Here's Code Snipet :

```
                        UIView *viewForCell = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, 5, 140, 170)];
                        viewForCell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
                        viewForCell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
                        viewForCell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                        viewForCell.tag = indexPath.row*100 + i;
                        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(horizanalPhotoItemTapped:)];
                        [viewForCell addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


                       -(void)horizanalPhotoItemTapped: 
                                    (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender//Photo
                        {
                         long selectedRowItem = sender.view.tag;
                         long selectedRow = selectedRowItem/100;
                         long selectedItem = selectedRowItem%100;

                     //    NSArray *arrNewsItems = [dictSelCategory valueForKey:@"items"];
                  NSDictionary *dictTappedRowItems = [arrNewsItemsOfTheSection objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
                        NSArray *arrHorizandalNewsItems = [dictTappedRowItems valueForKey:@"photoitems"];
                      NSDictionary *dictselectedNews = [arrHorizandalNewsItems objectAtIndex:selectedItem];
                       dictSelVideo = dictselectedNews;

                strPhotoBackBtnTitle = [dictThisCategoryNews valueForKey:@"title"];


                WebServices *webService = [[WebServices alloc] init];
                webService.delegate=self;
                webService.tag=TAG_HOMEPHOTOALBUM_REQ;
               [webService getDataFromURL:[dictselectedNews valueForKey:@"albumurl"]];
```

}

Comment: Full error message in console?

Comment: please remove this line viewForCell.tag = indexPath.row*100 + i;